# glmnet and error: "one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8 observations; dangerous ground"

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to write the script to an elastic net training model (machine learning). The data only have 22 rows. I provided a sample data frame- df. Then I turn the response variables into factors (for classification, rather than regression). Next, I create a list of the predictors- column names "age" through "ErythritolArea." That object is called "pred.names.min." I then partition the data- 65% for training, and 35% for the test data set. In the next step, I say that I want to use the "leave one out cross validation" method in training and have a random search tuning parameter (for alpha and lambda)- this is object tcontrol. Lastly, I specify the training model. I say that I want all names of variables in the predictor object ("pred.names.min") to be used for the training dataset ("trainingset") as predictors. Additionally, outcome is specified as trainingset$hpresponse1. The model produces the error "one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8  observations; dangerous ground." I am not sure what is causing it though. None of the variables listed in the predictor object are factor variables. The outcome is a factor. But if that variable produced that error, I don't know why. That variable has 14 rows, not 8. Can anyone tell what is producing that error?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(glmnet)
library(caret)

#creating sample dataset
df<-data.frame("L_TartaricacidArea"=
c(1,2,6,4,9,2,1,2,2,1,8),          
"Hydroxymethyl_5_furancarboxylicacidArea_2"=
c(2,4,6,1,8,9,1,9,2,6,4,1,2,6,4,9,2,1,2,2,1,8),           
"BMIfactor"=
c(1,8,6,1,2,9,2,2,9,2,1,2,4,6,1,8,9,1,9,2,6,4),          
"age"=
c(0,4,8,1,2,7,4,9,9,2,2,1,8,6,1,2,9,2,2,9,2,1),         
"Anhydro_1.5_D_glucitolArea"=
c(8,5,8,6,2,9,2,8,9,4,2,0,4,8,1,2,7,4,9,9,2,2),         
"LevoglucosanArea"=
c(6,2,9,2,8,6,1,8,2,1,2,8,5,8,6,2,9,2,8,9,4,2),  
"HexadecanolArea_1"=
c(4,9,2,1,2,9,2,1,6,1,2,6,2,9,2,8,6,1,8,2,1,2), 
"EthanolamineArea"=
c(6,4,9,2,1,2,4,6,1,8,2,4,9,2,1,2,9,2,1,6,1,2),           
"OxoglutaricacidArea_2"=
c(4,7,8,2,5,2,7,6,9,2,4,6,4,9,2,1,2,4,6,1,8,2),    
"AminopentanedioicacidArea_3"=
c(2,5,5,5,2,9,7,5,9,4,4,4,7,8,2,5,2,7,6,9,2,4),     
"XylitolArea"=
c(6,8,3,5,1,9,9,6,6,3,7,2,5,5,5,2,9,7,5,9,4,4),       
"DL_XyloseArea"=
c(6,9,5,7,2,7,0,1,6,6,3,6,8,3,5,1,9,9,6,6,3,7),            
"ErythritolArea"=
c(6,7,4,7,9,2,5,5,8,9,1,6,9,5,7,2,7,0,1,6,6,3),     
"hpresponse1"=
c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1),    
"hpresponse2"=
c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1))

#setting outcomes as factors
df$hpresponse1<-as.factor(df$hpresponse1)
df$hpresponse2<-as.factor(df$hpresponse2)

#creating list of predictor names
pred.start.min <- which(colnames(df) == "age"); 
pred.start.min
pred.stop.min <- which(colnames(df) == 
"ErythritolArea"); pred.stop.min
pred.names.min <- colnames(df) 
[pred.start.min:pred.stop.min]

#partition data into training and test (65%/35%)
set.seed(2)
n=floor(nrow(df)*0.65)
train_ind=sample(seq_len(nrow(df)), size = n)
trainingset=df[train_ind,]
testingset=df[-train_ind,]

#specifying that I want to use the leave one out cross- 
validation method and use "random" as search for 
elasticnet
tcontrol <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV",
                         search="random")


#training model
elastic_model <- train(as.matrix(trainingset[, 
pred.names.min]), trainingset$hpresponse1,
                       data = trainingset,
                       method = "glmnet",
                       trControl = tcontrol)
```

Comment: 14 rows, some are 1s and some are 0s. These are the classes. So there are less than eight 1s or there are less than eight 0s. That triggers the error, apparently.

Comment: Could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have 14 rows, some are 1s and some are 0s. These are the classes. With 14 rows total, in two classes there are either less than eight 1s or there are less than eight 0s (or if there are seven of each, less than eight in both classes). That triggers the error, apparently.